# How to change two lists' editmode separately

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

I have 2 lists in a vstack. I want to use 2 editbuttons to change the editmode of the 2 lists separately.

I know the 2 editbuttons will be associated with the same environment value of the struct EditModeInTwoLists like this:

```
struct EditModeInTwoLists: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            EditButton()
            List{
                ForEach(1..<5){_ in
                    Text("List1")
                }
            }
            
            EditButton()
            List{
                ForEach(1..<5){_ in
                    Text("List2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, I encapsulate the lists into 2 separate childviews. Because, IMO, the 2 childviews should have separate environment value. I change the code like this:

```
struct EditModeInTwoLists: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            EmbedList1()
            EmbedList2()
        }
    }
}

struct EmbedList1: View{
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            EditButton()
            List{
                ForEach(1..<5){_ in
                    Text("List1")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct EmbedList2: View{
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            EditButton()
            List{
                ForEach(1..<5){_ in
                    Text("List2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the 2 editbuttons also toggle synchronously. Do I misunderstand anything? Is there any way to toggle the 2 editbuttons separately?

EDIT:

@Asperi 's approach works for me. However, if I customize a button to toggle the wrappedValue of editmode, the issue appears again. I don't quite understand of the reason.

```
struct EmbedList1: View{
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Button {
                if editMode != nil{
                    editMode!.wrappedValue = editMode!.wrappedValue.isEditing ? .inactive : .active
                }
            } label: {
                Text(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true ? "Done" : "Edit")
            }
            
            List{
                ForEach(1..<5){_ in
                    Text("List1")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what exactly `EditButton` does inside. Actually standard API is for standard things.

In such cases it is more appropriate to work with `EditMode` directly to have control over it.

Here is a possible approach (tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5)

[image: demo]

```
struct EmbedList1: View{
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive  // << own state
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            // own button to switch
            Button(editMode == .inactive ? "Edit" : "Done") {
                editMode = editMode == .active ? .inactive : .active
            }
            List{
                ForEach(1..<5){_ in
                    Text("List1")
                }
            }
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, $editMode) // << own env
    }
}

// do same inside EmbedList2
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTwoEdiatableLists.swift)

Comment: It works for me. Thank you!  If I use "@Environment(\.editMode)  var editMode" and toggle the "wrappedValue", it will be synchronous again. I'm a little confused. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: struct EmbedList1: View{
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Button {
                if editMode != nil{
                    editMode!.wrappedValue = editMode!.wrappedValue.isEditing ? .inactive : .active
                }
            } label: {
                Text(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true ? "Done" : "Edit")
            }
            
            List{
                ForEach(1..<5){_ in
                    Text("List1")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}